# Interactive "for each item in ... do ..." in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, batch

How does one interactively run a basic looping batch construct in QGIS?

```
for each {feature} in {features}:
    do {thing} with/to {feature}
    save/export/display {result}
```

Where:

- {features} could be a polygon shapefile, a table, a selected record set, ...
- {feature} an individual record from {features}
- {thing} is any Processing tool (or menu action?)

In ArcGIS [cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000009r000000), [batch processing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00210000000w000000), and [model iterators](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00400000001n000000) can be brought to bear for looping, though only the latter are interactive. What are the QGIS equivalents?

Most of the topics and tutorials I've looked at so far involve shell scripts or straight up python code -- meaning little to no interactivity and dynamism. Is this really the best/only way, at present? Essentially, I'm re-asking [Interactive "For each .... Do" loop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11623/interactive-for-each-do-loop) and hoping for a QGIS specific answer.

Comment: What are you trying to iterate through? There are enumerators for features and such that are similar to Esri.. would a 'for every feature in this layer' example help?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson yes exactly, 'for every feature in layer' or 'every feature in {selection}'

Answer (score 11):

*Some more quality time with a search engine and different keywords finally dropped me on the doorstep of the right learning lab (I did hunt through the docs earlier, honest!):*

Chapter 17, [The QGIS processing guide](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/index.html) of the QGIS Training Manual contains [Iterative execution of algorithms](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/processing/iterative.html#iterative-execution-of-algorithms), which finally revealed to me the magic *"Iterate over this layer"* button, present on all processing tool dialogs:

[image: iterate button]

When activated it automatically redirects the process to work on each feature within the layer, furthermore it also only operates on the selected features. Except for the ability to control the names for the outputs of each operation this perfectly suits the need which spawned this question. Beautiful.

Using only selected features is optional:

[image: Processing >> Options]

---

To round things out there is also the [Python Console](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#python-console), activated from the Plugins menu, where can [call the processing tools](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#calling-algorithms-from-the-python-console). It's wordy and a bit unwieldy (I've been spoiled by ArcGIS python console's interactive parameter hints) but very workable.

```
>>> import processing as processing
>>> processing.runalg(name_of_the_algorithm, param1, param2, ..., paramN,
         Output1, Output2, ..., OutputN)
```

To save repetitive strain I deal with the wordy part by using `import processing as p` or `as pr` instead.

I looked for but did not find the console syntax for the equivalent of pushing the iterate button when using *runalg()* -- a `p.runalg(... iterative=yes)`.  From [Additional functions for handling data](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#additional-functions-for-handling-data) it likely has something to do with `getfeatures(layer)`.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS has similar looping to Esri (arcpy) except skip cursors. Here's a bit of code to get you started:

```
# Import the PyQt and QGIS libraries
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

# iterate through layers
layermap = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
for name, layer in layermap.iteritems():
    if layer.isValid():
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            if layer.isEditable():
                # then it's an editable vector layer that's valid

# loop through selected features in the active layer
layer = self.canvas.currentLayer()
if not layer == None:
    if layer.isEditable():
        if layer.selectedFeatureCount() > 0:
            for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
                AttList = feature.attributeMap()
                for (key,Value) in AttList.iteritems():
                    # print the attributes for the feature...

# set the value of one attribute for one feature
layer = self.canvas.currentLayer()
FieldToUpdate = 2 # index of the field (0 based)
NewValue      = "New Value"
# direct... just do it!
layer.changeAttributeValue(UpdateFeatureID,FieldToUpdate,NewValue,True)

# by the feature (see previous iteration)
feature = QgsFeature()
layer.featureAtId(id,feature) # get feature by ID if you know it
feature.updateFeatureAttributes(FieldToUpdate,NewValue)
```

The help docs on QGIS python API aren't as good as the Esri (arcpy) help (IMO) but you can ususally get a sense of what's going on from the [Quatum GIS API Documentation (for C/C++)](http://qgis.org/api/1.8/annotated.html)

Comment: how would this be fired? Say I'm in qgis and have loaded a polygon shapefile and selected some of them. How do I push them to the operation/script?

Comment: Oh that's a different matter... perhaps worth a new question. You need to connect to signals (events) in the QOject class, you really need to create a complete plugin to access all the signals; have a read of http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html and then perhaps post a new question about creating a basic plugin responding to the selection changed signal.

Comment: I found a higher level doorway through the "iterate over layer" button, see other answer. There is room for another answer to show syntax for using embedded console `processing.runalg()` with `getfeatures(layer)` (or equivalent).

Comment: Processing.runalg() is like IFeatureLayer.Search() with a whereclause... at least that's the impression I get from it. The code I provided was from an addin I wrote for QGIS 1.6